# Python Minidom - how to iterate through attributes, and get their name and value

Tags: python, python-3.x, minidom

I want to iterate through all attributes of a dom node and get the name and value

I tried something like this (docs were not very verbose on this so I guessed a little):

```
for attr in element.attributes:
    attrName = attr.name
    attrValue = attr.value
```

1. the for loop doesn't even start
2. how do I get the name and value of the attribute once I get the loop to work?

Loop Error:

```
for attr in element.attributes:
  File "C:\Python32\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 553, in __getitem__
    return self._attrs[attname_or_tuple]
 KeyError: 0
```

I'm new to Python, be gentle please

Comment: Are you forced by circumstances to use minidom? The `xml.etree.ElementTree` is more comfortable.

Comment: Thanks, I assume I found no resources as minidom is not that used anymore... will try that...

Comment: On the other hand, if you use minidom instead of ElementTree your knowledge will transfer directly to just about any other programming language you might find yourself using.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a short and efficient (and pythonic ?) way to do it easily

```
#since items() is a tUple list, you can go as follows :
for attrName, attrValue in element.attributes.items():
    #do whatever you'd like
    print "attribute %s = %s" % (attrName, attrValue)
```

If what you are trying to achieve is to transfer those inconvenient attribute `NamedNodeMap` to a more usable dictionary you can proceed as follows

```
#remember items() is a tUple list :
myDict = dict(element.attributes.items())
```

see http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict
and more precisely example :

```
d = dict([('two', 2), ('one', 1), ('three', 3)])
```

Comment: I believe it's element.attrib, not element.attributes

Comment: element.attributes is correct for minidom. element.attrib is used in ElementTree

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after looking at [this (somewhat minimal) documentation](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/xml.dom.minidom.NamedNodeMap-class.html), I guessed to success the following solution

```
#attr is a touple apparently, and items() is a list
for attr in element.attributes.items():
    attrName = attr[0] 
    attrValue = attr[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

attributes returns a `NamedNodeMap` which behaves much like a dictionary, but isn't actually a dictionary.  Try looping over `iteritems()` of `attributes` instead.  (Keep in mind that looping over a regular dict loops over the keys anyway, so your code wouldn't work as expected in any case.)